# I want to return a value from a function

Tags: javascript, return-value

I want to return a value from the function which first gets it value from

```
<a onclick="swapper(2)" href="javaScript:void(0);" class="zmenubar"><div id ="change1" class="zyoyo"><li>2</li></div></a>
```

so the function swapper(valuate) gives valuate a value of 2 now
and my function goes like this

```
function swapper(valuate) {
    document.getElementById("qq" + valuate).style.display = "";
}
```

so i need a way to return value of valuate from the swapper to use somewhere else but i cant because everytime i try to write it or assign it by using swapper(valuate) it executes the function and everything goes haywire
so i would appreciate some help.

Comment: " to use somewhere else" Where else? The return value of onclick goes to the bit space. You could store a value to a global variable, and read it on "somewhere else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a global variable and store your valuate on to it. And use it anywhere in the document.

```
var globalValuate;
function swapper(valuate) {
    globalValuate = valuate; 
    document.getElementById("qq"+valuate).style.display="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a generic answer you can :

1- use global variables which are [not best practice](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_best_practices.asp)

2- you can use the browser and store the value as a cookie or use local storage.